# Change table name with sysdate

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to change a table name by appending `SYSDATE` to it. For example, I want to change table `EXAMPLE_TABLE` to `EXAMPLE_TABLE_05_01_2015`, but I want to get the date from `SYSDATE`.

I prepared the following but it is not working:

```
ALTER TABLE "MYDB"."EXAMPLE_TABLE" rename to (SELECT 'EXAMPLE_TABLE' || TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, '_dd_MM_yyyy') FROM DUAL);
```

How can I make it work?

Here is the error:

```
SQL Error: ORA-14047: ALTER TABLE|INDEX RENAME may not be combined with other operations
14047. 00000 -  "ALTER TABLE|INDEX RENAME may not be combined with other operations"
*Cause:    ALTER TABLE or ALTER INDEX statement attempted to combine
           a RENAME operation with some other operation which is illegal
*Action:   Ensure that RENAME operation is the sole operation specified in
           ALTER TABLE or ALTER INDEX statement;
```

Comment: What error is it returning you ?

Comment: You could do it in `SQL*Plus` using `variable substitution`. See my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `execute immediate`.

```
begin
   execute immediate 
   'alter table mydb.example_table rename to ' ||
   'example_table_' || to_char(sysdate, 'dd_mm_yyyy');
end;
/
```

That said, I have the hunch that you'd be better off using partitioned tables.

Comment: Great solution. Agreed on the second part as well, if this is part of your solution you should probably consider other options.

Answer (score 0):

In **`SQL*Plus`**, you could use the `variable substitution`.

**Just another way** :

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE t(ID NUMBER)
  2  /

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> COLUMN new_tablename NEW_VALUE new_tablename
SQL> SELECT 't_' || to_char(sysdate, 'dd_mm_yyyy') AS new_tablename from dual
  2  /

NEW_TABLENAM
------------
t_05_01_2015

SQL>
SQL> RENAME t TO &new_tablename
  2  /
old   1: RENAME t TO &new_tablename
new   1: RENAME t TO t_05_01_2015

Table renamed.

SQL>
SQL> select * from t_05_01_2015;

no rows selected

SQL>
```

So, now the table `T` is **renamed** to `T_05_01_2015`.